# how to detect when <input> tag is empty in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple search box that only uses Javascript and CSS to display results, I have a problem when the search input is empty the code doesn't respond as it should.

the search works fine when there is a matching result, however when there is no match found, I would like to show a message "no results" instead.

the HTML code I am using is as follow:

in header tag:

```
        <div class="searchDiv">
            <input onkeyup="searchAction()" name="main search" placeholder="بحث" type="text" />
            <img src="images/research.png" alt="search"/>
        </div>
```

in body : 
1. p tag with "no results message"
2.the result cards both initially display="none"

```
<div class="searchResults" style="display:flex;">
            <p id="noResults" style="display: none;">لا يوجد نتائج</p>
            <div data-name="كرات البطاطا" class="cardResult cook">
                <img src="images/balls.jpg" alt="كرات البطاطا">
                <a href="#">وصفة كرات البطاطا</a>
            </div> 
            <div data-name="كرات البطاطا" class="cardResult cook">
                <img src="images/balls.jpg" alt="كرات البطاطا">
                <a href="#">وصفة كرات البطاطا</a>
            </div> 
            <div data-name="كرات البطاطا" class="cardResult cook">
                <img src="images/balls.jpg" alt="كرات البطاطا">
                <a href="#">وصفة كرات البطاطا</a>
            </div>
```

the problem is that once that no message result shows it never disappear, I am using the following JS code:

```
function searchAction(event){
var Input = this.event.target.value;
var ResultsCards= document.querySelectorAll('.cardResult');
var ResultsDiv = document.querySelector('.searchResults');
var noResult = document.querySelector('#noResults');
noResult.style.display="none";
ResultsCards.forEach(card=>{
        const cardText = card.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].text;
        if(cardText.indexOf(Input)>-1 && Input!=null && Input!=""){ 
            noResults.style.display="none";
            card.style.display="flex"
        } else{
            noResults.style.display="none";
            card.style.display="none"
        }

        if(ResultsDiv.innerText == ""){
            noResults.style.display="block";
        }
    })}
```

Comment: Why do you have the input tag in the header, just out of curiosity?


Also, would it be possible for us to look at all of your code?

Comment: `if(ResultsDiv.innerText == "")` – when should this ever happen? The HTML content of that element _never_ changes. Did you think hiding children via CSS, would make them dispappear from the HTML content of the parent? That’s not how it works.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. But `display:none` will not remove the elements from DOM. Everything inside `ResultsDiv ` must be empty. Change your code according to that. Just make sure you `ResultsDiv` is empty by browser inspect elements.

Comment: Hello, I use <header> for navigation bar where the search box lives @TorNato

Comment: @CBroe I actually came up with this after testing it in the console, when that div is empty  innerText will be "" if not  it will show text inside <a> child tags

Comment: @TorNato I still didn't figure the problem, I am testing on the following site, www.fatenkitchen.com

Answer (score 0):

Replace '.innerText' with '.value' and then it should work.

```
if(ResultsDiv.value == ""){
  code;
}
```

Input tags have no innerhtml or inner anything because they have no closing tags. The contents of the input is in the value attribute.

```
<input value="foo">
```

would give you an input with the contents 'foo'.

Comment: div doesn't have value

Comment: `<div class="searchResults" style="display:flex;">`

Comment: He's using an input tag though. @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: To quote you... 'div doesn't have value'. Why were you talking about divs when they have  nothing to do with what I was talking about?

Comment: What's the first line of your answer?

Comment: I just copied that from his answer. I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the input whenever it changes, and make decisions based on it, like so:

```js
function onInputChange() {
  const newValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
  const outcome = document.getElementById("outcome");
  const isEmpty = newValue === "";
  if (isEmpty) {
    outcome.innerHTML = "No value to search";
  } else {
    outcome.innerHTML = `Searching for ${newValue}`;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" onkeyup="onInputChange()" placeholder="search here...">
<div id="outcome">No value to search</div>
```